# SpringBoot - Unknown Column "Enable"

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Can anyone help me with this error?

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'enabled' in 'field list'
```

When I'm logging in, I input the right username and password base from MySQL DB.
I don't even use encryption on my password and Not even using column "enabled" on my DB.

Any tutorial or suggestion would help me. Thank you, guys!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // add a reference to our security data source

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("appDataSource")
        private DataSource appDataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            // use jdbc authentication ... oh yeah!!!       
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(appDataSource);

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**","/templates/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateCredentials")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")  // after logout redirect to landing page (root)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

        }

}





@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {


    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController (UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

        //add user
        this.userService.save(user);

        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: but i haven't used that keyword. Can you expound sir? (Beginner Here)

Comment: Please make sure the column "enabled" exists in table "users"

Comment: Even I won't use it?  okay sir

Comment: I add that column but still doesn't work